# Prove inequality - Convex problem

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence such that $0\le q_1\le q_2\le \cdots\le q_n$. How can I prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n q_is_i\le q_n,$$
where $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n s_i = 1$ for all $s_i\ge 0$?

Comment: I tried Induction @Taroccoesbrocco

Comment: @Alex show your working, pls.

Comment: I accept Paprika answer. It is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence satisfies $q_i\leq q_n\;\forall\, i\in\{1,\,\ldots,\,n\}$.

Now consider these manipulations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n q_i s_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^n q_n s_i=q_n\sum_{i=1}^n s_i=q_n.$$